# sql server update double rounding from steps

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have this issue: in my database there's  a field that is a double value. I need that this value is rounded by a constant step:
for example I set a step of 20.0 and I wish that a value 17.8 become 20.0, a value of 31.2 become 40.0 etc..

how can I do this with a query?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @stepsize float = 20.0

declare @val float = 17.6

select CEILING(@val / @stepsize) * @stepsize    -- Result 20.0

set @val = 31.2

select CEILING(@val / @stepsize) * @stepsize    -- Result 40.0
```

It's unclear from your question what 6.0 should 'round' to with a stepzie of 20.0. Should it round down to zero?

Comment: That not what your original question states.

Answer (score 1):

You do this by dividing the value by the step, rounding it and then multiplying by the step.  Most SQL dialects have arithmetic functions.

Comment: It should be, do it to the right of the assignment in an update.

Comment: Almost.  The second step should be using a ceiling function, not a rounding function.  Walk through it with 31.2.

Comment: Yes, ceiling is correct to round up, or floor to round down or add .5 and round.